How to intercept/trap non-existing properties AND methods using JS Proxy?
I need to wrap an immutable object coming from 3rd party code to (a) override some methods and (b) to catch non-existing properties/methods because the object throws an error if a property/method does not exist.
I want to achieve a behavior similar to standard JS objects where non-existing properties simply return undefined and do not throw an error, like this:


const obj = {};
console.log(obj.foo); // undefined



JavaScript's Proxy implementation is very close to what I need but the problem is that the get trap does not know whether the property was actually read or called... what makes sense because get should just return the property.
Anybody has an idea how to solve this?
Example (error in last line):


// mock of immutable 3rd party object
class Target {
    bar = "bar";
    foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

const target = new Target();

const handler = {
    // intercept (trap) accessing properties, including methods
    get: function (target, prop) {
        // return undefined if property not exists
        if (!(prop in target)) {
            return undefined;
        }
        // otherwise return the existing property
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
};

// wrapper
const proxy = new Proxy(target, handler);

console.log(proxy.foo()); // 'foo'
console.log(proxy.bar); // 'bar'
console.log(proxy.nonExistingProperty); // undefined
console.log(proxy.nonExistingMethod()); // proxy.nonExistingMethod is not a function



In my case, I need something like:
const handler = {
    get: function (target, prop) {
        if (!(prop in target)) {
            // returns function (returning undefined) if method not exists or undefined if property not exists
            return __wasCalled__ ? () => undefined : undefined;
        }
        return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
}; 

Or the Proxy API would need another trap for callable properties, like this:
const handler = {
    // trap non-existing properties
    get: function (target, prop) {
        return !(prop in target) ? undefined : Reflect.get(...arguments);
    },
    // trap non-existing methods (actually non-existing properties that were called)
    call: function (target, name, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        return !(name in target) ? () => undefined : Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
    }
};


If the property isn't there, return another Proxy object instead of undefined and trap apply on that. Otherwise, you'll have to lean on the safe navigation operator (or something) from the calling side, e.g.: proxy.nonExistingMethod?.().

@canon It's called "optional chaining".

I already tried this but doesn't work either because then calling proxy.nonExistingMethod() works as expected but getting proxy.nonExistingProperty returns a Proxy object (type object or function) instead of undefined. Can you share a code snippet?

@Barmar "or something" was meant as "or an alternative." But safe navigation and optional chaining are synonymous concepts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

@droptix that's the trade-off; pick your poison.

@canon But it's called optional chaining in all JS documentation, AFAIK. Just as we call dictionaries "objects" in JS.

The simple answer is that there's no way to get precisely what you want, because the proxy doesn't know how the result will be used.

"the get trap does not know whether the property was actually read or called": it is always a get. If there is a call that will be made, it first needs the get to return, and then the one using that property result may decide to call it, or to wait 5 minutes and then call it, or decide to not call it even when it is a function (realise that a function is an object, and you can do much more things with it than just calling it). There is some misunderstanding in your question when it comes to that.
